# Adding records to a CollectionViewSource resource, not showing up in a bound ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, collectionviewsource

First, this is my first attempt at using WPF.  I'll try to spare as much information as possible, since this data-entry form is a little less than typical.  However, if more information is needed, please ask.

I have a WPF window with a series of `CollectionViewSource` objects in my `Window.Resources` collection.  These are initialized in my window's constructor.

One of these collections is an `IList<T>` where `T` is of a POCO type used with Entity Framework.

My form has a section of user-input controls.  When the user hits the `Save` button, I need to create an entity and add it to my `IList` collection.

So far, I've had no trouble.  I can create the entity, and I can add it to the collection without any issue.  However, the problem is that I have a `ListView` control that is bound to this collection.  I can, and have verified, that I can load records to this list *when the Window initializes in the constructor*.  However, when I click my `Save` button, the collection gets updated, but the UI does not refresh the operation.

For reference, here is the pertinent code below.

**SetResource() - Called in the constructor of my Window**

```
    private void SetResources()
    {
        ... other objects...

        //myCacheSrc is property defined in my Window.cs file.
        myCacheSrc = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("myCacheSrc");
        myCacheSrc.Source = new List<MyEFPOCO>();

        ... more initializations of other objects.
    }
```

**Contents of my Save button click event**

```
    private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cache = myCacheSrc.Source as List<MyEFPOCO>;
        if (cache != null && !CurrentRecord.Equals(origCurrentRecord))
        {
            cache.Add(CurrentRecord);
        }
    }
```

It is worth mentioning, I've stepped through the above block of code.  It is executing on the save event, and the `CurrentRecord` property does contain a valid entity.

Here is a my Window constructor.  Notice that there is a test insert operation.  This works!  Note, it's not much different than the code in my button event.  Why would this work, and not the button event?

**Window Constructor**

```
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetResources();

        //TEST
        var cache = myCacheSrc.Source as List<MyEFPOCO>;
        if (cache != null)
        {
            cache.Add(new MyEFPOCO
                { 
                    userEntryType = "TEST",
                    numberValue= 1234567
                });
        }
    }
```

**MyWindow.xaml - Declaration of the ListView in question**

```
        <ListView Name="CachedChangesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCacheSrc}}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Name="UpdateChange" Content="{StaticResource iUpdate}" Width="20" />
                        <Button Name="DeleteChange" Content="{StaticResource iDelete}" Width="20" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding userEntryType}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding numberValue}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ObservableCollection Instead of List, Because it will notify the UI about the source change. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 myCacheSrc = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("myCacheSrc");
        myCacheSrc.Source = new ObservableCollection<MyEFPOCO>();
```